# Cell Separator Style

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can we set Separator style at cell level. i.e. each cell will be having different separator style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set the cell separator style per cell.  You might try setting the table view separator to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and then draw a custom "separator" yourself when you render out each cell.

**Edit:** How to do it depends a lot on your current code, what type of table, whether you are using a custom table cell, what exactly you mean by "different separator style", etc.

I have not tried this, but one option I can think of off the top of my head would be to use the `UITableViewCell.backgroundView` property.  You could add a subview with a different color that is only a few pixels high along the bottom or you could create a `UIImageView` that fills the `backgroundView` and set the image to achieve the "different" separator.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give me a sample code on how to write this custom separator?